# Take the input of a queue of integers as an input and convert it to a queue with squared elements

Tags: python, queue

squareElems: A function that takes a queue of integers as an input and converts it to a queue containing the same elements squared. For example, if the input queue initially contains (2, 4, 6 8), then applying this function should change its contents to: (4, 16, 36, 64).

class Queue:

```
def __init__ (self):
    """Create an empty queue."""
    self._data = [ ] # nonpublic list instance

def __len__(self):
    """Return the number of elements in the queue."""
    return len(self._data)

def is_empty(self):
    """Return True if the queue is empty."""
    return len(self._data) == 0

def enqueue(self, e):
    """Add element e to the rear of the queue."""
    self._data.insert(0, e) # new item stored at the beginning of the list

def peek(self):
    """Return (but do not remove) the element at the  front of the queue. Raise Empty exception if the queue is empty. """
    if self.is_empty():
        raise QueueEmpty('Queue is empty')
    return self._data[-1] # the last item in the list

def dequeue(self):
    """Remove and return the element from the front of the queue (FIFO). Raise Empty exception if the queue is empty. """
    if self.is_empty():
        raise QueueEmpty("Queue is empty")
    return self._data.pop() # remove the last item item from list

   
def __str__(self):
    stack_rep = "Current contents of the queue:\n"
   
    for el in self._data:
        stack_rep +=str(el) + ' '
       
    return stack_rep

def sqaureElems(self):

    def sqaure(n):
        return n**2

    number = int(input('Please enter a number: '))
    number2 = square(number)
    return number2
       
           
    print('Current contents of the queue:')
           
    print('Calling sqaureElems() on the queue...:')
    print('Current contents of the queue')
```

def main():

```
st = Queue()
st.is_empty()
st.enqueue(2)
st.enqueue(4)
st.enqueue(6)
st.enqueue(8)
st.peek()
st.dequeue()
```

if **name** == "**main**":
main()

The output show looked like:

Current contents of the queue
2 4 6 8

Calling sqaureElems() on the queue...

Current contents of the queue:
4 16 32 64

Comment: You pretend _The output show looked like:
… 2 4 6 8_ while in fact it's `8 6 4 2` - perhaps you're confused by your equating `the rear of the queue` with `the beginning of the list`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your requirements correctly, you can do something like this:

```
from queue import Queue


def sqaure_elems(q):
    q.put("STOP")

    while (item := q.get()) != "STOP":
        q.put(item * item)
        q.task_done()

    q.task_done()

def main():
    q = Queue()

    for item in range(2, 10, 2):
        q.put(item)

    sqaure_elems(q)

    while not q.empty():
        print(q.get())
        q.task_done()

    q.join()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Note:**

The walrus operator (`:=`) is available since **Python 3.8+**.